# Second server UNION ALL displays same output data from first query with equal timestamp

Tags: sql-server, ssms

After running my `UNION ALL` query I have the same output data on the second query with equal timestamp output data. How I could gather the same output data if the area2 server has different vendors with timestamps, could the output same data be due to the order on the bottom of the query, I have tried the following query.

[Current table data from both servers, AREA1 with AREA2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGs3T.png)

**QUERY**

```
DECLARE @Invoice_Date SMALLINT;

SET @Invoice_Date = 2020;

SELECT DISTINCT 'AREA1' AS 'Server',
    *
FROM (
    SELECT Name,
        Vendor,
        Invoice_Date,
        count(*) Count_InvoiceNo,
        rank() OVER (
            PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY count(*) DESC
            ) rn
    FROM dbo.Invoices
    WHERE Invoice_Date >= '2020-01-01'
    GROUP BY Name,
        Vendor,
        Invoice_Date
    ) t
WHERE rn = 1
    AND InvDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, - 12, GETDATE())

UNION ALL

SELECT DISTINCT 'AREA2' AS 'Server',
    *
FROM (
    SELECT Name,
        Vendor,
        Invoice_Date,
        count(*) Count_InvoiceNo,
        rank() OVER (
            PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY count(*) DESC
            ) rn
    FROM dbo.Invoices
    WHERE Invoice_Date >= '2020-01-01'
    GROUP BY Name,
        Vendor,
        Invoice_Date
    ) t
WHERE rn = 1
    AND Invoice_Date >= DATEADD(MONTH, - 12, GETDATE())
ORDER BY SERVER,
    Invoice_Date
```

Comment: Bear in mind - we don't have your tables or your data and we can't see what you're seeing. *Help us to help you*. Create the simplest query you can that demonstrates the problem,. including just the necessary columns, then add the minimal table definitions, sample data, your expected result and what you're seeing.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - my question has been updated and I also have included an image displaying table same equal output data from both servers.

Comment: Images don't help us reproduce what you're seeing locally on our machines, such that we can try making changes, etc. At the moment, the two queries joined by the UNION ALL look identical to me so I'd be surprised if they didn't show the same data.

Comment: Perhaps, server union all should not be utilized if query appears correct.

Comment: From what I can understand you are asking why AREA1 and AREA2 data is the same. The reason is that you have two identical queries in your `UNION ALL`, hence result duplication. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Alex - Area1 always has less monthly invoices, and different vendor transactions, I should be able to view more invoices from AREA2 from input database invoices per month. They should be differentiated with month to month from AREA1 to AREA2 with vendors invoices.